# Promise based function inside stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

One of my functions isn't executed. I've tried several promised based approaches from new Promise and then chains inside and outside the function and inside the stream and turning it into an async and await function, but nothing seems to work.

```
const urlExists = require('url-exists');
const csv = require('csvtojson');

csv().fromStream(s3Stream)
         .on('data', (row) => {
             let jsonContent = JSON.parse(row);
            checkColumnMissing(i, jsonContent.CommonNames, 'CommonNames');
            //The function below seems to get skipped.
            checkImages(i, jsonContent.ImageFemale, 'ImageFemale');            
    })

function checkColumnMissing(i, val, column){
    if(val === null || typeof val === 'undefined' || val === ""){
        errReturned.push(`Row ${i} Error: Column ${column} is missing a value`);
     }
}

function checkImages(i, image, type){
    const url = `https://someurl`;
    urlExists(url, function(_, exists) {
        if(!exists){
            errReturned.push(`Row ${i} Error: Image ${type} not found in zip`); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

How can I get the function checkImages to execute within the stream?

Comment: you're running into an error most likely; wrap `checkColumnMissing` in a try-catch to see more. also, i have NO clue how your variable `i` was created

Comment: Sorry var i was part of the above snippet function, which I missed to add. Lambda gives me the results of checkImages the second time the function runs. My guess is it's getting cached. The rest of the function works fine.

Comment: ah yes, you are using lambda...so your function is returning immediately bc its not waiting for the stream to finish. You need to make your stream return a promise...kinda like this article https://humanwhocodes.com/snippets/2019/05/nodejs-read-stream-promise/